# Cause Kontrol to exit once a path has confirmed to cause an issue

Tags: formal-verification, kontrol

I am running the [kontrol](https://docs.runtimeverification.com/kontrol/guides/kontrol-example/property-verification-using-kontrol) formal verification tool, and it has been running for over 1.5 hours.

Is there a way to tell the tool to quit on finding a path that breaks the assertion? That way I don't have to wait so long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `kontrol prove` with `--fail-fast` option will instruct Kontrol to stop executing other branches if a failing node is detected. The description of existing options in Kontrol is available via `kontrol --help`, but we will add `--fail-fast` to the [Kontrol Cheatsheet](https://docs.runtimeverification.com/kontrol/cheatsheets/kontrol-cheatsheet) in our documentation. Thanks for reporting!

Please note that, like Foundry, Kontrol reports all failures and reverts, including but not limited to assertions.